# vertx with mysql have low tps performance

Tags: vert.x

i try to combine vertx with mysql to do some code refactoring. first i use vertx-jdbc-client, but the tps seems no good, about 400 transaction per second, seems that so much time wasted in waiting to get the sql connection, but i had closed the connection after transaction commit/rollback, then i took vertx-mysql-client for instead, which is similar, about 480 transaction/ second, i had looked up the officesite documention for many times, followed the example codes, tried so many tunning options, just as vertical instance number, blockinghandler, blockingexecute, connectin pool size, tcp options, native transport etc, but i can't figured out why has so low tps performance.

contrast to the vertx, i use the springboot webflux, jpa and Schedulers.parallel(), the tps up to 1300 per second, it is so weird.

my legacy code used springboot undertow, servlet 3.1 and jpa, the tps was rather low.

the vertx qps will up to 27000 per second if without mysql query or trasanction in my stress test.

```
VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions().setPreferNativeTransport(true);
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions);
vertx.registerVerticleFactory(springVerticleFactory);

DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(CpuCoreSensor.availableProcessors());
vertx.deployVerticle(SpringVerticleFactory.PREFIX + ":" + MainVerticle.class.getName(), deploymentOptions);

@Slf4j
@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Value("${server.port:8080}")
    private Integer port;
    private JDBCClient jdbcClient;

    public void start(Promise<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
        /*Map<String, Object> properties = Maps.newHashMap();
        properties.put("maxLifetime", 1700000);
        properties.put("cachePrepStmts", true);
        properties.put("prepStmtCacheSize", 250);
        properties.put("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", 2048);
        properties.put("useServerPrepStmts", true);
        properties.put("useLocalSessionState", true);
        properties.put("rewriteBatchedStatements", true);
        properties.put("cacheResultSetMetadata", true);
        properties.put("cacheServerConfiguration", true);
        properties.put("elideSetAutoCommits", true);
        properties.put("maintainTimeStats", false);

        JsonObject config = new JsonObject()
                .put("jdbcUrl", "jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx:3306/db?characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=GMT%2B8&sslMode=DISABLED&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=true")
                .put("provider_class", "io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.HikariCPDataSourceProvider")
                .put("driverClassName", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                .put("username", "user")
                .put("password", "user")
                .put("minimumIdle", 10)
                .put("maximumPoolSize", 10)
                .put("datasource", properties);
        jdbcClient = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, config);*/

        MySQLConnectOptions connectOptions = new MySQLConnectOptions()
                .setPort(3306)
                .setHost("xxxxxxx")
                .setDatabase("db")
                .setUser("user")
                .setPassword("user")
                .setCachePreparedStatements(true)
                .setPreparedStatementCacheMaxSize(250)
                .setPreparedStatementCacheSqlLimit(2048)
                .setTcpFastOpen(true)
                .setTcpKeepAlive(true)
                .setTcpNoDelay(true)
                .setTcpQuickAck(true)
                .setReusePort(true);
        PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(10);
        MySQLPool client = MySQLPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions);

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        router.route().method(HttpMethod.POST).method(HttpMethod.PUT).consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE).handler(BodyHandler.create().setHandleFileUploads(false));

        router.post("/api/test/post")
                .handler(HTTPRequestValidationHandler.create()
                        .addFormParam("id", ParameterType.GENERIC_STRING, true)
                        .addFormParam("partition", ParameterType.GENERIC_STRING, true)
                        .addFormParam("code", ParameterType.GENERIC_STRING, true)
                        .addFormParam("amount", ParameterType.DOUBLE, true)
                        .addFormParam("num", ParameterType.GENERIC_STRING, true))
                .handler(routingContext -> {
                    String id = routingContext.request().getFormAttribute("id");
                    String partition = routingContext.request().getFormAttribute("partition");
                    String code = routingContext.request().getFormAttribute("code");
                    BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(routingContext.request().getFormAttribute("amount"));
                    String num = routingContext.request().getFormAttribute("num");

                    client.begin(transactionAsyncResult -> {
                        if (transactionAsyncResult.failed()) {
                            routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end(Json.encode(TestResult.fail(Errors.OPERATE_FAILED)));
                            return;
                        }

                        Transaction tx = transactionAsyncResult.result();
                        tx.preparedQuery("select id from test_account where customer_id = ? and partition_id = ? and code = ? and user_type = ? and trans_type = ?")
                                .execute(Tuple.of(id, id, code, "xxx", "xxx"), rowSetAsyncResult -> {
                                    if (rowSetAsyncResult.failed()) {
                                        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end(Json.encode(TestResult.fail(Errors.OPERATE_FAILED)));
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    String id = rowSetAsyncResult.result().iterator().next().getString(0);
                                    Tuple tuple = Tuple.of(amount, amount, id, amount);
                                    tx.preparedQuery("UPDATE test_account SET available = available - ?, non_avalibale = non_avalibale + ? WHERE id = ? and available >= ?").execute(tuple, rowSetAsyncResult1 -> {
                                        if (rowSetAsyncResult1.failed()) {
                                            routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end(Json.encode(TestResult.fail(Errors.OPERATE_FAILED)));
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        int rowcount = rowSetAsyncResult1.result().rowCount();
                                        if (rowcount == 0) {
                                            routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end(Json.encode(TestResult.fail(Errors.OPERATE_FAILED)));                                                                                              
                                            return;
                                        }

                                        List<Tuple> jsonArrayList = Lists.newLinkedList();
                                        Tuple jsonArray = getTuple();
                                        jsonArrayList.add(jsonArray);
                                        jsonArray = getTuple();
                                        jsonArrayList.add(jsonArray);
                                        tx.preparedQuery("INSERT INTO test_transaction_log (id, created_by, created_time, last_modified_by, last_modified_time, version, account_type, trans_type, qty_begin, qty_end, us_type, chg_type, code, cu_id, in_address, out_address, partition, record_type, remark, status, trans_amount, trans_number, tx_id, website, trans_type) " +
                                                "VALUES (?, 'system', now(), 'system', now(), 1, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, NULL, ?, ?, ?, 'SUCCESS', ?, ?, NULL, 'zh', ?)").executeBatch(jsonArrayList, listAsyncResult -> {
                                            if (listAsyncResult.failed()) {
                                                tx.rollback(rollbackcontext -> {
                                                    routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end(Json.encode(TestResult.fail(Errors.OPERATE_FAILED)));
                                                });
                                            } else {
                                                tx.commit(commitcontect -> {
                                                    routingContext.response().end(Json.encode(TestResult.SUCCESS));
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                    });

                    /*jdbcClient.getConnection(result -> {
                        if (result.failed()) {
                            routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end(Json.encode(TestResult.fail(Errors.OPERATE_FAILED)));
                            return;
                        }

                        SQLConnection conn = result.result();
                        conn.setAutoCommit(false, voidAsyncResult -> {
                            if (voidAsyncResult.failed()) {
                                conn.close(h -> {
                                    routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end(Json.encode(TestResult.fail(Errors.OPERATE_FAILED)));
                                });
                                return;
                            }

                            log.info("time spend -2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "--" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
                            JsonArray params = new JsonArray().add(id).add().).add(code).add("xxx").add("yyy");
                            conn.querySingleWithParams("select id from test_account where id = ? and partition_id = ? and code = ? and user_type = ? and trans_type = ?", params, jsonArrayAsyncResult -> {
                                if (jsonArrayAsyncResult.failed()) {
                                    conn.close(h -> {
                                        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end(Json.encode(TestResult.fail(Errors.OPERATE_FAILED)));
                                    });
                                    return;
                                }
                                String id = jsonArrayAsyncResult.result().getString(0);
                                JsonArray uparams = new JsonArray().add(amount.doubleValue()).add(amount.doubleValue()).add(id).add(amount.doubleValue());
                                conn.updateWithParams("UPDATE test_account SET available = available - ?, non_avalibale = non_avalibale + ? WHERE id = ? and available >= ?", uparams, updateResultAsyncResult -> {
                                    if (updateResultAsyncResult.failed()) {
                                        conn.rollback(rollbackcontext -> {
                                            conn.close(h -> {
                                                routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end(Json.encode(TestResult.fail(Errors.OPERATE_FAILED)));
                                            });
                                        });
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    log.info("time spend -4 " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "--" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
                                    List<JsonArray> jsonArrayList = Lists.newLinkedList();
                                    JsonArray jsonArray = getEntityArray();
                                    jsonArrayList.add(jsonArray);
                                    jsonArray = getEntityArray();
                                    jsonArrayList.add(jsonArray);

                                    conn.batchWithParams("INSERT INTO test_transaction_log (id, created_by, created_time, last_modified_by, last_modified_time, version, account_type, trans_type, qty_begin, qty_end, us_type, chg_type, code, cu_id, in_address, out_address, partition, record_type, remark, status, trans_amount, trans_number, tx_id, website, trans_type) " +
                                            "VALUES (?, 'system', now(), 'system', now(), 1, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, NULL, ?, ?, ?, 'SUCCESS', ?, ?, NULL, 'zh', ?)", jsonArrayList, listAsyncResult -> {
                                        if (listAsyncResult.failed()) {
                                            conn.rollback(rollbackcontext -> {
                                                conn.close(h -> {
                                                    routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end(Json.encode(TestResult.fail(Errors.OPERATE_FAILED)));
                                                });
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            conn.commit(commitcontect -> {
                                                conn.close(h -> {
                                                    routingContext.response().end(Json.encode(TestResult.SUCCESS));
                                                });
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });*/
                });

        router.route().failureHandler(routingContext -> {
            log.warn("handler error", routingContext.failure());
            routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end(Json.encode(Exceptions.map(routingContext.failure(), false)));
        });

        HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions()
                .setTcpFastOpen(true).setTcpNoDelay(true)
                .setTcpQuickAck(true).setReusePort(true);
        vertx.createHttpServer(options).requestHandler(router).listen(port, http -> {
            if (http.succeeded()) {
                startFuture.complete();
            } else {
                log.error("http server start failed", http.cause());
                startFuture.fail(http.cause());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to make any suggestions. What sounds suspicious is "closing the connection after transaction", and I would investigate where are you opening those connections.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin i added the codes, pls help pointing out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

That's not a definitive solution, but there are two problematic points I see in this code:

1. Connection pool is too small
2. Too much work is done on EventLoop

For the first problem, note that you're doing three separate DB operations: select, update and insert, using the same transaction, meaning the same connection. This is one probable bottleneck you're hitting.

For the second problem, I would suggest breaking this into at least 3 separate verticles communicating over event bus.

1. RequestHandler
2. Verticle to select the correct row
3. Verticle to perform operations on this row

That should also allow you to better interleave the work produced by different requests.

Comment: increase the pool size to 50, almost the same. codes will be hard to maintain if splitted to multiple verticles, but i will have a try.

Comment: what is the thinking behind breaking this into three separate verticles?

Comment: Gives you better resource utilisation. The actual explanation would be too long for a comment, but the way all reactive frameworks work is by putting tasks on a work stealing thread pool of some sort. The smaller the tasks, the better .